# Указание множества параметров через оператор побитового или

Tags: c++

Я часто вижу такую конструкцию

```
someFunction(param1 | param2 | param3);
```

Как она работает потому-что в Google информацию найти не смог.

Comment: Ну сначала выполняется побитовое или между первыми двумя параметрами, потом между полученным результатом и третьим параметром, и т.д. Что тут непонятного?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в файле заголовка указанные константы получат значения с единицей в разных позициях (в двоичном представлении), например, так:

```
#define param1 0b001
#define param2 0b010
#define param3 0b100
```

То при их объединении с помощью оператора ИЛИ будут получаться коды, которые затем можно анализировать в таком стиле:

```
if(yourvalue & param1) function1();
if(yourvalue & param2) function2();
if(yourvalue & param3) function3();
```

Answer (score 0):

На примере рассмотрим:

```
01011
ИЛИ
00110
=
01111
```

Смысл в том, что просто применяется логическое ИЛИ к каждой паре битов. Оба операнда равны 0 - тогда на этой позиции будет 0, если хотя бы один операнд равен 1, то и в результате на этой позиции будет 1. В Вашем примере выполняется та же операция, только для 3 чисел.

Answer (score 0):

Все ниже псевдокод (псевдо-python). Пусть

```
PARAM1 = 0b0001
PARAM2 = 0b0010
PARAM3 = 0b0100
```

При объединении с помощью логического или получаем:

```
PARAM1 | PARAM2 | PARAM3 = 0b0111
```

Это похоже на сложение, за тем исключением, что если мы добавим один и тот же параметр несколько раз, то переноса в следующий двоичный  разряд не произойдет:

```
PARAM1 | PARAM2 | PARAM3 | PARAM2 = 0b0111
```

Внутри функции получаем значение `0b0111`, и разбираем его по отдельным параметрам с помощью битового "и":

```
if arg & PARAM1:  # получаем ноль, если нужный бит выключен, или не ноль если включен
    действие1

if arg & PARAM2:
    действие2

if arg & PARAM3:
    действие3
```

Т.е., если включен бит, соответствующий какому-то из параметров, то соответствующее действие выполнится.